# Android Studio: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle

Tags: java, database

The error is as follows:

```
Build version: 2.5.2 
Build date: 1981-01-01 01:01:02 
Current date: 2024-01-18 16:29:48 
Device: Google sdk_gphone64_arm64 
OS version: Android 14 (SDK 34) 
 
Stack trace:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0(RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:74)
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.$r8$lambda$PhMGW5zFk4QWazERd2lfEeLZqW0(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: scaleUsers(com.health.openscale.core.datatypes.ScaleUser).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='scaleUsers', columns={birthday=Column{name='birthday', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isMilkORS=Column{name='isMilkORS', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, gender=Column{name='gender', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, goalDate=Column{name='goalDate', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, initial_wb2=Column{name='initial_wb2', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, bodyHeight=Column{name='bodyHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isH2O=Column{name='isH2O', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, goalWeight=Column{name='goalWeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, measureUnit=Column{name='measureUnit', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isSecondary=Column{name='isSecondary', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, AWI=Column{name='AWI', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, assistedWeighing=Column{name='assistedWeighing', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, leftAmputationLevel=Column{name='leftAmputationLevel', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, rightAmputationLevel=Column{name='rightAmputationLevel', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isCTC=Column{name='isCTC', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isPrimary=Column{name='isPrimary', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, DWI=Column{name='DWI', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, initialWeight=Column{name='initialWeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, activityLevel=Column{name='activityLevel', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, username=Column{name='username', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, scaleUnit=Column{name='scaleUnit', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, goalEnabled=Column{name='goalEnabled', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='scaleUsers', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, username=Column{name='username', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, birthday=Column{name='birthday', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, bodyHeight=Column{name='bodyHeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, scaleUnit=Column{name='scaleUnit', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, gender=Column{name='gender', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, goalEnabled=Column{name='goalEnabled', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, initialWeight=Column{name='initialWeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, goalWeight=Column{name='goalWeight', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, goalDate=Column{name='goalDate', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, measureUnit=Column{name='measureUnit', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, activityLevel=Column{name='activityLevel', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, assistedWeighing=Column{name='assistedWeighing', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, leftAmputationLevel=Column{name='leftAmputationLevel', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, rightAmputationLevel=Column{name='rightAmputationLevel', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, DWI=Column{name='DWI', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, AWI=Column{name='AWI', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, initial_wb2=Column{name='initial_wb2', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, isPrimary=Column{name='isPrimary', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, isSecondary=Column{name='isSecondary', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, isH2O=Column{name='isH2O', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, isCTC=Column{name='isCTC', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, isMO=Column{name='isMO', type='FLOAT', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.kt:94)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:253)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:416)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableOrReadableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:232)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.innerGetDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:190)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:151)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:104)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:638)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:457)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.kt:486)
    at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.kt:75)
    at com.health.openscale.core.database.ScaleMeasurementDAO_Impl$5.call(ScaleMeasurementDAO_Impl.java:863)
    at com.health.openscale.core.database.ScaleMeasurementDAO_Impl$5.call(ScaleMeasurementDAO_Impl.java:860)
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0(RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:72)
    ... 5 more
```

It currently looks like that the generated table to save in the database does not match the expected output.

Here's the code where the variables to be saved were created, initialized, and set.

#Initializing variables

```
@NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isPrimary")
    private float isPrimary;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isSecondary")
    private float isSecondary;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isH2O")
    private float isH2O;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isCTC")
    private float isCTC;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isMilkORS")
    private float isMO;

    // More code...

    isPrimary = 0.0f;
    isSecondary = 0.0f;
    isH2O = 0.0f;
    isCTC = 0.0f;
    isMO = 0.0f;

    //More code

    public void setIsPrimary(float isPrimary) {
        this.isPrimary = isPrimary;
    }
    public float getIsPrimary() {
        return isPrimary;
    }

    public void setIsSecondary(float isSecondary) {
        this.isSecondary = isSecondary;
    }

    public float getIsSecondary(){
        return isSecondary;
    }

    public void setIsH2O(float H2O) {
        this.isH2O = H2O;
    }
    public float getIsH2O() {
        return isH2O;
    }

    public void setIsCTC(float isCTC) {
        this.isCTC = isCTC;
    }

    public float getIsCTC(){
        return isCTC;
    }

    public void setIsMO(float isMO) {
        this.isMO = isMO;
    }

    //More code...

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format(
                "id(%d) name(%s) birthday(%s) age(%d) body height(%.2f) scale unit(%s) " +
                "gender(%s) initial weight(%.2f) goal enabled(%b) goal weight(%.2f) goal date(%s) " +
                "measure unt(%s) activity level(%d) assisted weighing(%b)",
                id, userName, birthday.toString(), getAge(), bodyHeight, scaleUnit.toString(),
                gender.toString().toLowerCase(), initialWeight, goalEnabled, goalWeight, DWI, AWI, initial_wb2, goalDate,
                measureUnit.toString(), activityLevel.toInt(), assistedWeighing, isPrimary, isSecondary, isH2O, isCTC, isMO);
    }
}
```

**Here is where the Migration is:**

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_9_10 = new Migration(9, 10) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // Add new columns to the scaleUsers table
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE scaleUsers ADD isPrimary FLOAT NOT NULL default              0");
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE scaleUsers ADD isSecondary FLOAT NOT NULL default 0");
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE scaleUsers ADD isH2O FLOAT NOT NULL default 0");
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE scaleUsers ADD isCTC FLOAT NOT NULL default 0");
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE scaleUsers ADD isMO FLOAT NOT NULL default 0");

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            database.endTransaction();
        }
    }
};
```

I apologize for the formatting.

I have double checked that I have incremented the version number properly. I have checked that the database accepts float. I had to change the variables from Boolean to Float after initializing after realizing it didn't accept boolean expressions. I have also double - checked all necessary variables and fucntions as well as comparing everything to toher variables for reference.

**Question:** Is it possible that after the initialization of the variables into the database, it rejects it now? I also changed variable names.